# Call php function using html href

Tags: php, html

I am searching for some hours today and I can not find the solution.
Here is the phpfuntion inside of the html href, which uses explode php-build-function to split the email and get the chars after @.

```
<a href='<?php echo afterchar('@',$nazwa_uz_l); ?>'>Log in <?php afterchar('@',$nazwa_uz_l); ?></a>
```

While I click the link it goes to localhost/gmail.com instead of gmail.com.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
<a href='http://<?php echo afterchar('@',$nazwa_uz_l); ?>'>Log in <?php afterchar('@',$nazwa_uz_l); ?></a>
```

The URL is relative if there's no protocol (http://) leading the URL.

Comment: To explain further the URL is *relative* if there's no protocol (`http://`) leading the URL.

Comment: No Problem, also thanks to Albert Xing for extrapolating my answer.

Comment: Thank you both. It works. And I do not even need an echo. I will accept the answer. Why I am getting so many minuses...

Comment: Don't worry about it, at least you got the answer you wanted :)